# A large box keeps appearing above the form

Tags: php, html, css

I have a small problem with my website's contact page. Whenever I use php for the form another large box appears above the form as if there was a additional set of `<p>` tags there; I am not sure why this keeps happening.
Here is the code.

Update: I have removed the box problem but now I have to figure out the css to change so that the form fits in with the rest of the webpage, and auto; doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cromika Web Designs - Contact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm() {
    var theName = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var theEmail = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var theMessage = document.getElementById('message');
    var emailerr = document.getElementById('emailspan');
    var nameerr = document.getElementById('namespan');
    var messageerr = document.getElementById('messagespan');
    var message;
    var myregex = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    if(theName==""){
        message = 'Name is required;';
        document.form1.name.focus();
        nameerr.innerHTML = message;
        return false;
    } else{
        nameerr.innerHTML ="";
    }
    if(theEmail=="") {
        message = 'Email is required;';
        document.form1.email.focus();
        emailerr.innerHTML = message;
        return false;
    } else if (!myregex.test(theEmail)){
        emailerr.innerHTML = "Your email entry is invalid;";
        document.form1.email.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        emailer.innerHTML ="";
    }
    if(theMessage.value=="" || theMessage.value ==null || theMessage.value.indexOf('\n') > 0) {
        message = 'Please enter your message;';
        document.form1.message.focus();
        messageerr.innerHTML = message;
        return false;
    } else {
        messageerr.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
      <header><img src="images/simple-logo.png" alt=""</img> </header>
      <nav>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="about.html" class="current">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="contact.php" class="current">Contact</a></li>
           <li><a href="gallery.html" class="current">Gallery</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
     <h1> Contact me!</h1>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send_email'])){
        // collect the form values
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        // set the email properties
        $to = 'email@email.com';
        $subject = "Contact Form Submission";
        $from = $email;
        $headers = "From: $from";
        // attempt to send the mail, catch errors if they occur
        try {
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            $msg = "<strong>Your mail was sent successfully!</strong>";
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $msg = "An Exception was thrown: ".$e -> getMessage()."<br>";
        }
    }
?>

    <table align="left">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" onSubmit="return checkForm()">
    <tr><th>Name:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br><span style="color:red;" id="namespan"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><th>Email:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br><span style="color:red;" id="emailspan"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><th>Message:</th>
        <td><textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea><br><span style="color:red;" id="messagespan"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="send_email" value="Send Email Message" /></td></tr>
    </form>
    </table>


    <footer></footer>
   </body>

</html>
```

And here is the CSS for the site

```
    @charset "UTF-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    
    body{
        font-size:16px;
        cursor:default;
        font-family:Georgia, serif;
        background-color:#000000;
        color: white;
        }
    
            
    header {
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 12px;
            height: 71px;
        }
    nav { 
            border-radius: 5px;
            height: 20px;
            width: auto;
            display: block;
            text-align:center;
            padding-right: 35px;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color:#8000aa;
            padding-top: .05px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            margin-top: 12px;
            margin-bottom: 12px;}
            
    nav li { 
            display: inline;
            float: center;
            }
    
    nav a {
    
        display: block, inline;
        width: 60px;
        
    }
    /*link styles*/
    a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
        
    }
    
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: white;
    }
    
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: blue;
    }
    
    a:active {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    /* end link styles */
    
    /* main content */
    
    h1 {
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            background-color: #8000aa;}
    table {
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 36px;
        height: 150px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top:12px;
        padding-bottom:12px;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        background-color: #8000aa;
}
    p {
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top:12px;
            padding-bottom:12px;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            background-color: #8000aa;}
    
    p a {
        font-weight: bold;
        }
    
    /* end main content*/
    
    footer {
            border-radius: 5px;
            clear: both;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top:12px; 
            padding-bottom:12px;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            font-weight:bold;
        background-color:#8000aa;}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: check the code for that box using "Inspect Element" and see where its actual code lies for it to appear...

Comment: @ManojSalvi I have tried that the thing is where the extra box appears is where the php code block would be which is right above the table and it the extra set of <p> tags doesnt exist in my actual files.

Comment: why did you put your form inside <p> tags??

Comment: Your HTML is very broken. You can't put `<form>` tags inside a `table` like that. Make sure that correct all HTML errors first. Use https://validator.w3.org/ to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `<p>` and `</p>` from around the table you use for your form. While on my test system this didn't put an actual box, it certainly pushed the form part well down the page.

FYI, I used Google Chrome and right click and select `Inspect Element` and it's showed up quite quickly.

Comment: Okay I changed that since that is fixed i added the table to my css so all i have left to do is work out how to fit the forms box to the rest of my page. THanks for your help so far!

Comment: Your welcome @Cro68. If the answer worked for you, would appreciate you marking it as such. Have fun.